# Accessing a file in a folder of theme with two parameters in wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, templates, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

In wordpress I want to show data from custom table. For this I created custom template and in that achieved from `global $wpdb`. I dont want any categories and posts of wordpress. I want to use wordpress for only static pages. I created one pluggin and storing data from this pluggin. So I need to show this data in the front end.

So far I created only one page from backend. So my problem is I need a links like these
http://localhost/application/medical/parameter1/parameter2

Here I created only one medical page from backend and added custom template. If run this url: http://localhost/application/medical/parameter1/parameter2.
It is redirecting to 404 page because parameters will not be send through the url.Here is the 2nd uri segment is medical and 3rd segment is parameter1 and 4th segment is parameter2. 
Based on these segments I need to get data from database. I am assuming this is a htaccess problem.

How do I set htaccess for getting this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you checked the documentation @ https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb where it says that you can use wpdb to refer other tables as well

Comment: Why don't you use regular Wordpress pages, use custom templates to stylise different pages and save all custom information on custom fields (post metas)?

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding. Yeah we can use wordpress core functionality. But the problem is I have same post names in different categories. For example Article in Press is the post name in medical category as well as in biology category. If we create we are getting article-in-press-1 as url slug in biology category.Because this we are getting problem in SEO, client does not want this kind of url. What I planned is I dont want use any posts, pages or custom post types. I created one pluggin I need to show data using uri segments in the front end.I'm planning to use wordpress only for staticpages